# Converting KMZ to SHP using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, kmz

I have several KMZ files that i want to import into QGIS, when i import any one it contains many features with different geometries and i only need the points one

the problem is when i try to merge them using mmqgis it says that i cant merge those layers saying that (points != 2.5d points) ,so:

1) is there a way to merge all those points without losing the data?

2) is there a way to detect the (2.5d points) and separate them so i can normally merge all the other points and i would manually add those points myself?

Comment: What is 2.5d points, and what data that points contain?

Comment: not sure what is 2.5d points, but when i try to merge all the layers in mmqgis it say that it cant merge 'points' and '2.5d points'..so i assume they're considered as different features

Comment: 2.5d points have a Z value for elevation. You can only merge features which have the same geometry type. There is a conversion function in mmqgis which you should be able to use to convert your 2.5d points to points. You should then be able to perform the merge.

Answer (score 3):

You want to convert the KMZ to SHP. When you open the KMZ layer in QGIS, layers appears on the Layer's Panel. With a right clic on it, you can SAVE AS and define Shape file.